# Connection string property of SqlConnection is not initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, string, connection

I have already searched for the error

> the connection string property has not been initialized.

on Google as well as on Stack Overflow but couldn't find the solution. I have created a database class for interaction with database all related code is written in this file. The problem is same code runs fine on other pages and it just don't work on a page called "addevent.aspx" I don't understand the reason why it is not running properly.

Here are the methods that I created in database.cs file

```
public void CreateConnection()
{
    var ConfiguredString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionString].ConnectionString;
    obj_sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(ConfiguredString);

}

//This property will set the connection string for database
public string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {   //if _connectionString is already created or set, only then it will return the value of _connectionString
        if (_connectionString != string.Empty && _connectionString != "" && _connectionString != null)
            return _connectionString;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
    // When you want to set the connection string set block is called.
    set
    {   // this line sets the connection string to the _connectionString data member for the first time.
        if (_connectionString == string.Empty || _connectionString == "" || _connectionString == null)
            _connectionString = value;
    }
}

// Open database connection.    
public void OpenConnection()
{
    obj_sqlconnection.Open();
}

// Close database connection.
public void CloseConnection()
{
    obj_sqlconnection.Close();
    obj_sqlconnection.Dispose();
}

public SqlConnection GetCurrentConnection
{
    get { return obj_sqlconnection; }
    set { obj_sqlconnection = value; }
}
```

I simply don't understand the logic of this error and its occurrence. I get this error when I open the connection

How do I call these methods, I have already created a object of database.cs class outside the method AddEvent with object name mydb

```
public int AddEvent(string _title, string _description, string _place, int _eventTypeID, string _startingTime, string _endingTime, string _startingDate, string _endingDate, string _creatorID, string _picture)
{
    string[] blacklist = { _title, _description, _place, _picture };

    if (Jvalidate.FilterBlackLIstKeywords(blacklist))
    {
        int eventid = Convert.ToInt32(mydb.GetLastValueByColumnName("event_id", "tbl_events"));
        int rowsaffected = 0;
        mydb.CreateConnection();

        mydb.InitializeSQLCommandObject(mydb.GetCurrentConnection, "spAddEvent", true);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventID", eventid + 1);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", _title);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", _description);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", _place);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventType", _eventTypeID);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startingTime", _startingTime);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endingTime", _endingTime);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", _startingDate);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", _endingDate);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolID", SchoolID);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventCreatorID", _creatorID);
        mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventPicture", _picture);
        try
        {
            //mydb.obj_sqlconnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cesConnectionString"].ToString();
            mydb.OpenConnection();
            rowsaffected = mydb.obj_sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            mydb.CloseConnection();
            mydb.obj_sqlcommand.Dispose();
        }
        return rowsaffected;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show how do you use this class methods

Comment: i have updated the post. Kindly view it there

Comment: From this code I cannot be sure where this errore comes from. On which line do you get the exception? Did you try to use the debugger to check the state of the connection when the exception happen?

Comment: yes i debug the program and when it hits the line obj_sqlconnection.Open(); the error occurs

Comment: and before executing the obj_sqlconnection.Open(); it has initialized/have value of connectionstring coming from web.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's too complicated solution... this will solve your problem of understanding and unnecessary code lines:

solution:

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public static class Solution
    {
        static readonly string _connectionStringName =
            @"mainConnectionStringName";

        static readonly string _connectionString =
            _connectionStringName.getConnectionString();

        // string extended method like .ToLower() or .Trim()
        public static string getConnectionString(
            this string connectionStringName)
        {
            return
                System.
                Configuration.
                ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].
                ConnectionString;
        }

        public static object SqlExecute(
            string connectionStringName,
            string storedProcedureName,
            System
                .Collections
                .Generic
                .Dictionary<string, object> parameters,
            bool isScalar)
        {
            object result = null;

            using (System
                      .Data
                      .SqlClient
                      .SqlConnection connection =
                new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionStringName)
                        ? _connectionString
                        : connectionStringName.getConnectionString()))
                if (connection != null)
                    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command =
                        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()
                        {
                            CommandText = storedProcedureName,
                            CommandType = System
                                             .Data
                                             .CommandType
                                             .StoredProcedure,
                            Connection = connection
                        })
                        if (command != null)
                        {
                            if (parameters != null)
                                foreach (System
                                            .Collections
                                            .Generic
                                            .KeyValuePair<string, object>
                                                pair in parameters)
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                                        pair.Key, pair.Value);

                            command.Connection.Open();

                            result = isScalar
                                ? command.ExecuteScalar()
                                : command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            if (command.Connection.State ==
                                    System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                                command.Connection.Close();
                        }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public sealed class SomeClass
    {
        public int Example()
        {
            return (int)Stackoverflow
                .Solution
                .SqlExecute(
                    @"anyConnectionStringName", // or null for main connection string
                    @"anyStoredProcedureName",
                    new System
                        .Collections
                        .Generic
                        .Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        { @"field0", "value" },
                        { @"field1", -1.5 },
                        { @"field2", System.DateTime.Now },
                        { @"field3", 3.5 },
                        { @"field4", 7 },
                    },
                    false // for ExecuteNonQuery or true for ExecuteScalar
                );
        }
    }
}
```